# Using rand() c in OMP causing dependencies

Tags: c, dependencies, openmp

Hi im am using OMP to parallelise my code. I am stuck with some dependencies i believe however i am unsure. Currently my code builds a graph to use for Dijkstra's algorithm later in my program. I understand that t is private to each thread however does the fact that im using rand() generate a different set of numbers on each thread than if i ran it sequentially? I ask this because the results im getting for my sequential version are different to my parallel. Or have i missed a different dependency that is causing my code to change?

```
    long linkCnt;
    long i,j;
    long t;

    srand(randInit);

    //Initialize Matrix
    for(i = 0; i< G->N; i++)
    {
        linkCnt=0; //Keep track of # of outgoing edges
     #pragma omp parallel for schedule(runtime) private(t)
        for(j = 0; j < G->N; j++)
        {

            if(i == j){
                t = NO_CONN;
            } else {
                t = (rand() % ((MAX_EDGE_WEIGTH-1) * 2)+1); //50% of having no connection
                if(t > MAX_EDGE_WEIGTH){
                    //t = INF; //Like no connection
                    t = NO_CONN; //Like no connection
                } else {
                    linkCnt++;
                    G->visited[j] = VISITED; //Do this to find isolated nods that have no incomming edge
                }
            }

            G->node[i][j] = t;
        }

        //Be sure to only generate fully connected graphs by each node having at least one edge to someone else!
        if(linkCnt == 0)
        {
            printf("Adding outgoing link for [%d]\n", i);
            t = rand() % (G->N);

            if(t == i) //NO self loops
                t = (t*t)%G->N;

            G->node[i][t] = rand() % (MAX_EDGE_WEIGTH);
        }
    }
  }
```

The variables look like this:

```
#define INF INT_MAX
#define NO_CONN -1
#define NOT_VISITED 1
#define VISITED 2
typedef struct {
    long N; //Number of nodes
    char** node; //Matrix of Nodes and connections

    int* D; //Result of Dijkstra Algorithm. Shortest path length for each node.
    char* visited; //Used to flag which nodes have been visted yet or not.
} graph;
```

Comment: The `rand()` function is not thread-safe.  It uses a single static variable to hold state.  You need a more sophisticated PRNG if you want separate threads to have their own separate deterministic (but still pseudo-random) sequences.

Comment: A reentrant rand_r() is available, but with weak entropy, drand48 and friends are another option.  Some more info here https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand , https://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48